# tika: disable looking inside zip files

Tags: java, apache-tika

Currently, `tika` is processing zip files looking inside them.

I'd like to disable this features and only gets me `application/zip` mime type.

I'm using this code right now:

```
public String getMimeType(InputStream is) {
    TikaConfig tikaConfig = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
    Detector detector = tikaConfig.getDetector(); //new DefaultDetector();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(TikaInputStream.get(is), metadata);
}
```

This code returns me zipped mime type file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Disable the other detectors? http://tika.apache.org/1.18/configuring.html#Configuring_Detectors

Comment: Do you suggest me I disable ZipContainerDetector? How tika will detect zip mime types without this detector? Could you provide an answer?

Comment: It'll just use Mime Magic detection then, not the class that peeks inside the Zip to see which sub-type it is

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example I wrote a dummy app. I then used a large Zip file that doesn't have the zip Extension. I do not see the behavior that Tika parses the whole file.

I looked with a debugger. Tika only reads 65536 bytes to determine the file type.

See: Tika MimeTypes.class:154

```
public MediaType detect(InputStream input, Metadata metadata)             throws IOException {
    List<MimeType> possibleTypes = null;

    // Get type based on magic prefix
    if (input != null) {
        input.mark(getMinLength());
        try {
            byte[] prefix = readMagicHeader(input);
            possibleTypes = getMimeType(prefix);
        } finally {
            input.reset();
        }
    }
```

dummy app

```
import org.apache.tika.config.TikaConfig;
import org.apache.tika.detect.Detector;
import org.apache.tika.io.TikaInputStream;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.mime.MediaType;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(new Main().getMimeType(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\temp\\apache-tomcat-8.0.47-windows-x64"))));
  }

  public String getMimeType(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    final TikaConfig tikaConfig = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();

    Detector detector = tikaConfig.getDetector(); //new DefaultDetector();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(TikaInputStream.get(is), metadata);
    return mediaType.getType();
  }
```

Maven:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Can you show me an example that reads and parses the whole zip-file? I can understand that that would be a problem when files exceed a certain size.

Unfortunately I cant help you if I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry @Dave. It's not fine for me. I need to say to tika to disable `ZipContainerParser` or something similar in order to not analize zip files.

Comment: Do you know any way to get that?

Comment: I am looking into it and am writing a dummy app. As I have understood you don't want to parse the contents of a zip file but just return that it is a Zip mimetype.

Comment: Yes, I need exactly that!

Comment: You have to add `tika-parsers` dependencies. Only adding that you're going to be able to reproduce that behavior.

Comment: You can probe using little zip size files.